How can we reduce the gap between the TextFormField and validation message error
I want to remove the space between the TextFormField and the validation error message in Flutter which comes when we validate the form using formState.validate()
I tried to find out the reason for that space it is caused by the static variable
static const double subtextGap = 8.0;

How can we override this value and make it to 0

You can use conentpadding to reduce spacebetween TextFormfield and error message, Example:
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, right: 3, top: 14, bottom: 14),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, height: 0.3),
    // Other properties...
  ),
  // Other properties...
),

Or can be used like this also contentPadding:EdgeInsets.all(0)

I have removed the content padding but still there is a space between the form field and Error message due to the default value of subtextGap in InputDecoration. Is there any way to override this value please let me know.

The subtextGap in InputDecoration is a static constant and cannot be directly overridden. you can achieve a similar effect by customizing the errorStyle,  errorStyle: TextStyle(
height: 0.8, // Adjust line height to reduce space
), Hope this may help you.
